# Getting a FileNotFoundError for writing a text file

Tags: python

So I have been trying to write a text file in a specific directory with the following code (note_value and note_title are variables already set to a string) :

```
file = open("resources/user_notes/" + note_title + ".txt", "w")
file.write(note_value)
file.close()
```

When I try this I get the following error :

```
file = open("resources/user_notes/" + note_title + ".txt", "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'resources/user_notes/the.txt'
```

The directory I am using does exist, I have even copied the directory path from my file explorer to python, and it still doesn't work.  If you know the solution to this please let me know.

Comment: Is resources folder in your current path, or is it somewhere else?

Comment: The resources folder is in the same folder as the script running this code.

Comment: What about the `user_notes` subdirectory, does that already exist?

Comment: Also, do you guys know how to select which part of my text is code, I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: user_notes is in the resources folder.

Comment: *the same folder as the script running this code* is not necessarily the same thing as the current directory.

Comment: I would advise using os.path.join to create your path rather than string concatenation. So file = open(os.path.join('resources', 'user_notes', note_title + '.txt'), 'w'). Also, can you try putting print 
 os.path.abspath(os.path.join('resources', 'user_notes')) in your script to see where the script thinks resources folder is

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice.

Comment: So for some reason, my script just started randomly working, so I'm good, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with joining?

```
import os
fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/resources/user_notes/the.txt')
with open(fn, 'r') as readfile: 
    for line in readfile:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem while writing to multiple text files from Python. Most of the files had no issue, but a few resulted in

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IO/INDUSTRIES.txt'`

Turns out the "/" in filename was causing the issue. This means that due to "/" my filename is "INDUSTRIES.txt" which resides in the "IO" folder, which is not true. So removing the "/" resolves this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While removing the `'/'` character from your string resolved your problem, there is no `'/'`character in the question's `note_title` variable.  So aside from the same exception class, your answer is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

1.please check the working directory or change the relative path to absolute path.
2.make sure the variable note_title does not contains "/" or some other special character.

Comment: I would change the relative path to an absolute path, but I plan on possibly publishing my python script, and I don't know where the user of my script would put the folder for my script.

Comment: Also I have made sure note_title does not have any /'s.